# How to cast from stream to a streamreader in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

This is my code

```
String^ fileName ="filename";
StreamReader din =File::OpenText(fileName);
```

and its showing error

```
cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::IO::StreamReader ^' to 'System::IO::Stream ^'
```

Please help I am new to c++ also I am doing it in visual studio 2010

Comment: This is managed C++ not regular C++ you should tag accordingly.

Comment: @Alex Farber again I am getting error by not opening the file. So if I use this code where should I open the file.

Answer (score 0):

The `StreamReader` class has a constructor that accepts a `Stream^` as argument.